# About the thread_union in understanding the linux kernel 3rd edition

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Is the description here fully correct?

In page 86 of "UnderStanding The Linux Kernel 3rd Edition", "Identifying the current process"

The thread_info structure shown in Figure 3-2 is stored starting at address 0x015fa000 , and the stack is stored starting at address 0x015fc000 . The value of the esp register points to the current top of the stack at 0x015fa878.

See the union definition.

## "the stack is stored starting at address 0x015fc000":

1.Regarding the union:
  If using &thread_union.stack to get the starting address of stack, then it should be same as &thread_union.thread_info, with value 0x015fa000.

2.As the stack grows down, then when fetching the start address of stack, the is a small computing like &thread_union.thread_info + 4*2048, or &thread_union.thread_info[2048].

Right?

```c
union thread_union {
  struct thread_info thread_info;
  unsigned long stack[2048]; /* 1024 for 4KB stacks */
};
```

Comment: There is a note in the [errata](https://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596005658): **Change "the stack is stored starting at address 0x015fc000" to 
"the stack is stored at addresses below 0x015fc000"**.

Comment: Great, it is found and updated, thanks.